# How to retrieve health data from Google Fit service in android

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-fit

I'm writing an Android program to retrieve specific type of health data. I read google documentation for retrieve data from users, but I cannot retrieve at the end. Could anyone help to resolve this problem by simplest way of java. My current code attached here with.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 156;
GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount=null;

//Request Data for STEP_COUNT_DELTA with READ permissions
//FitnessOptions - API
FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .build();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    //Get instance of Google Account
     googleSignInAccount = googleSignInAccount(fitnessOptions);


    if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(googleSignInAccount, fitnessOptions)) {
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this, // your activity
                GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE, // e.g. 1
                googleSignInAccount,
                fitnessOptions);
    } else {

            accessGoogleFit();

    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {

            accessGoogleFit();
        }
    }
}

private void accessGoogleFit() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = new Date();
    cal.setTime(date);

    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    //SessionReadRequest sessionReadRequest = new SessionReadRequest.Builder().read(DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY).setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();

    DataReadRequest dataReadRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder().read(DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY).setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();

    Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).readData(dataReadRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {

                    List<DataSet> dataSets = dataReadResponse.getDataSets();
                    for(DataSet dataSet: dataSets){
                        for(Field field: dataSet.getDataType().getFields()){
                            if(field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(FitnessActivities.SLEEP)){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ENCONTRADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });

}





public GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount(FitnessOptions fitnessOptions) {
    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions);
    return account;
}
}
```

By this code archive google authentication with user before access *google fit -api*, all the *api* access implemented at *accessGooogleFit()* function

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59905977/295004 Please don't repost questions.

Comment: okay now!, thank for your request

Comment: @HirunRashmitha asking another question two days after your first and then deleting your first is not how things work here.  If your first question didnt get an answer then improve it dont open another one in two days. Its unclear what the issue is with your current code.

Comment: @DaImTo thank you for your suggestions, I'm new to hear. Everything learn from your words. ^^Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet got from Google API documentation

```
SessionReadRequest request = new SessionReadRequest.Builder()
        .readSessionsFromAllApps()
        // Activity segment data is required for details of the fine-
        // granularity sleep, if it is present.
        .read(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
        .setTimeInterval(1576690819, 1576750401, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

Task<SessionReadResponse> task = sessionClient.readSession(request);

task.addOnSuccessListener(response -> {
    // Filter the resulting list of sessions to just those that are sleep.
    List<Session> sleepSessions = response.getSessions().stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getActivity().equals(FitnessActivities.SLEEP))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (Session session : sleepSessions) {
        Log.d("AppName", String.format("Sleep between %d and %d",
                session.getStartTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                session.getEndTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS)));

        // If the sleep session has finer granularity sub-components, extract them:
        List<DataSet> dataSets = response.getDataSet(session);
        for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
            for (DataPoint point : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                // The Activity defines whether this segment is light, deep, REM or awake.
                String sleepStage = point.getValue(Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY).asActivity();
                long start = point.getStartTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                long end = point.getEndTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Log.d("AppName",
                        String.format("\t* %s between %d and %d", sleepStage, start, end));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But this snippet not provide the expected return output could you please add the documentation link?

Comment: Is this the answer to your question?